# How do you create a global error handler for an es2017 javascript async/await function?

Tags: javascript, async-await, bluebird

Bluebird 3.4.1 for promises,
Chrome 56,
Babel 6.23.1

Given:

```
  async login() {
    try {
      let response = await this.authservice.login('invalid-credentials');
    } catch (error) {

    }
  }
```

The above code simulates a 401 response error with a json object with the specific error message returned from the server which does trigger the catch statement.  But instead of having to handle the error for each catch statement I would like to have a global error handler.

In non async functions I use the `window.onerror` event which works as expected.  However this does not work for async functions.

I have also added events for

```
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection')
window.addEventListener('rejectionhandled')
```

these events do not trigger for the above case(they do trigger for other cases).  Instead bluebird returns "warning a promise was rejected with a non-error: [object Response]".

The `this.authservice.login` is using a library that uses the standard promise syntax versus async functions.

I can get the error to eventually bubble up to the unhandledrejection event if I throw a new error in the catch statement.  However the above function is called from another function and I have to throw an error in both functions in order for the global unhandledrejection to fire.

In short I am trying to make a global error handler for all async/awaits and promises.

Comment: Every async chain should have its own error handling (it's own catch).  You simply can't properly handle errors from the top level.  So, if you're asking this because you don't want to handle errors locally, that is a flawed set of thinking.  Rejections needs to be handled in the code that is managing that promise, not as some higher level that has no idea what just happened of how to deal with it properly.  If you want to use a common error handler for separate multiple functions, you can do that with a simple wrapper.

Comment: Yes I was looking at not handling errors locally but what you said makes sense and I will just use a wrapper instead.  I was a little confused on how the unhandledrejection and rejectionhandled worked but I have since got a better handle on things.  Thanks.

Comment: @jfriend00 That's kind of a bad take. The reason errors/exceptions typically bubble is precisely to allow the nearest relevant code to handle the error. You don't want to couple the entirety of your application to every async chain (i.e., each async call shouldn't have to know how to handle/route errors that are outside of its scope). A call to `fetch` to update a field should not have to know about how to handle an esoteric networking error.

Comment: @coreyward - Well, promise rejections only propagate if you propagate them somehow or write your code in a way that they will naturally propagate.  If your code chooses to ignore a rejection, they don't go anywhere.  That's just how the promise design works.  So, if you have some higher level handler that you want them to go to, you HAVE to make sure that the rejection will propagate to that handler by how you write your code.

Comment: @coreyward - If you do `fetch(...).then(...)` and have no reject handler, a reject from that promise doesn't naturally propagate anywhere without you writing some code to make sure it does propagate where you want it to go.  That is just how promises work in Javascript.  I'm not the designer of that, just telling you how it works and what your responsibilities as a programmer in Javascript are.

Comment: @jfriend00 You're absolutely right about how JS works, but I was replying to your opinion about where the responsibility ought to lie: "So, if you're asking this because you don't want to handle errors locally, that is a flawed set of thinking. Rejections needs to be handled in the code that is managing that promise, not as some higher level that has no idea what just happened of how to deal with it properly." 

It dismissed the question as being a "flawed" approach, but despite the technical challenges, it's a good question.