# Redux Thunk not trigging "window.onerror" event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, error-handling, redux

I'm trying to add global error logging using `window.onerror` as outlined in the [accepted answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31111771/can-you-catch-all-errors-of-a-react-js-app-with-a-try-catch-block).

I have it working when I throw an error in one of my component lifecycle methods and synchronous redux actions. However, errors thrown from an async `thunk` action do NOT get caught by my handler.

Is this expected?  Is there some way I can catch these errors in a global handler?

```
export const syncReduxAction = (): Action => {
  throw 'This will trigger window.onerror';
};

export const asyncReduxAction = (): ThunkAction<Promise<T>, GlobalState, void> =>
  async (dispatch, getState) => {
    throw 'This will NOT trigger window.onerror';
}
```

### Update

[According to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448538/how-do-you-create-a-global-error-handler-for-an-es2017-javascript-async-await-fu), it looks like async errors are in fact not handled by the `window.onerror` event handler.

But even if I catch the error and rethrow it:

```
this.props.dispatch(asyncReduxAction())
.catch((e)=> {
   throw new Error(e);
  }
);
```

It doesn't trigger the event!